# Typescript error while using .find function : This expression is not callable

Tags: typescript

Env:

```
typescript 4.5.5
```

Errors

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ <S extends User>(predicate: (this: void, value: User, index: number, obj: User[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S | undefined; (predicate: (value: User, index: number, obj: User[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): User | undefined; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

Error Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the `users` definition states it is either Array of `User` or Array of string.

You can change the definition to `const users: Array<User | string> = res.data;`.

This way while looping will be aware that the element inside an array can be both `User` or string.

Or if in your case you are sure that the users array can either be an array of `User` or `string` but not both, then you can keep the definition of `users: User[] | string[]`, but trick Typescript while `.find` like `(users as Array<User | string>).find((x: User | string) => {// find logic})`

Comment: Tracking issue upstream: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373

Comment: If you don't want to manually distribute the types, you can use a little helper type like this: `type Ugh<T> = (T extends (infer X)[] ? X : never)[]`. Then, you can do something like `(users as Ugh<typeof users>).find(...)`.  just rename `Ugh` in your actual code…